# What is the state of transmissible vaccines?

Tags: medications, vaccination, virus, coronavirus

I was thinking about viral gain of function research -- and firebugs playing with matches -- when it hit me: if a highly contagious, but harmless version were engineered it could outcompete more dangerous ones and inoculate large groups. Also, it would presumably be effective as a nasal spray.

Given how commonplace gain of function studies are, why is [transmissible vaccination](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5777272/) -- arguably loss of function research -- not an equally active field of research?